# How to detect a shape in an image using MSE method in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Here is my code:

```
function Score=ScoreFindPicture_SSE_loop(I,P)
D=double(~(P==2));
P_new=P*255;
[rP, cP]=size(P);
[rI ,cI]=size(I);
ScoreMin=zeros;
for i=1:(rI-rP+1)
    for j=1:(cI-cP+1)
       E=(I(i:i+rP-1,j:j+cP-1)-P_new).*D;
       SE=E.*E;
       SSE_I=sum(sum(SE));
       ScoreMin(i,j)=SSE_I;
   end
end
Score=1./ScoreMin;
end
```

"I" is the double format matrix of the image,and "P" is the matrix of the special shape that I'm searching for on the image,
the function works properly but it is slow,I'm going to write this function without loop to speed up,I think  two nested 2-d convolution may work but I can't figure out how to implement it,any help would be appreciated.

The shape is as following(D shows "don't care"):[The shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGcA9.png)

[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vnSX.png)

Comment: Have you checked this Matlab function?: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html

Comment: Yes but it can not verify the shape in some case,I want to write the above program without using loop.

Comment: actually my image is made of black and white pixels and I'm looking for a shape in it.

Comment: Edit your question with sample images so it's easier to see what you are trying to do. I solved a similar problem with black and white images using a unique convolution, hence my first comment.

Comment: @Eskapp I edited the question.